# Cannot decode token in python created in ASP.NET using secret

Tags: python, c#, jwt, base64, pyjwt

Secret is created in .Net using below code

```
var key = new byte[32];
RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create().GetBytes(key);
var base64Secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Encode(key)
Audience newAudience = new Audience { ClientId = clientId, Base64Secret = base64Secret, Name = name };
```

Token is created in .Net using below code

```
string symmetricKeyAsBase64 = audience.Base64Secret;    
var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);
var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);
var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;
var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);
```

Above code successfully created a token which needs to be decoded in python:

Secret is `XYZ` which is generated and stored in the database. Secret is encoded using `TextEncodings.Base64Url.Encode` before storing into the database. I tried to decode the secret key in python by adding a "="

```
base64.urlsafe_b64decode("XYZ=")
```

I also tried by adding double equal "==" using below method

```
base64.b64decode("XYZ==")
```

Fianlly I tried above two methods to decode the secret and use it in `jwt.decode()`

```
jwt.decode(token, secret, algorithms=['HS256'])
```

None of the things worked.

Token looks like

```
HEADER:ALGORITHM & TOKEN TYPE

{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256"
}
PAYLOAD:DATA

{
  "unique_name": "devuser",
  "sub": "devuser",
  "role": [
    "Manager",
    "Supervisor"
  ],
  "iss": "https://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net",
  "aud": "6A00574AE5514C1C90D2D5332FEF78F9",
  "exp": 1596636265,
  "nbf": 1596634465
}

**VERIFY SIGNATURE**
HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
)
```

Comment: so what's the problem now? *None of the things worked.* - this is not a sufficient error description. Is it again padding error? At least you should have learned from the linked duplicates in the older question that the base64 string should be of a length dividable by 4, so adding two '=' doesn't make sense. I also checked last time that your python code was working when you have a JWT that was signed with a base64 encoded secret. So maybe the C# side is the problem. Show your C# generated token.

Comment: when I use that token, with the given secret (padded with one "=") and this code: `decoded = jwt.decode(token, secret)` I get an `ExpiredSignatureError('Signature has expired')` error. If I try with another token, made with the same secret and non expired on jwt.io, decoding works fine.

Comment: so you're editing question and answer for security concerns but use a secret that was copied from a tutorial and can be found [more than 250 times on google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=IxrAjDoa2FqElO7IhrSrUJELhUckePEPVpaePlS_Xaw%3D)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the secret needs padding. Altough Base64Url encoding usually [does not require padding](https://base64.guru/standards/base64url), the Python Base64 decoder wants it.
So the secret is:

```
XYZ=
```

(padded to 44 characters).

Without padding you would get:

> binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

And then your token contains an [audience claim](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#audience-claim-aud) and PyJWT has to verify the audience.

Quoting the above linked documentation:

> If the principal processing the claim does not identify itself with a value in the “aud” claim when this claim is present, then the JWT MUST be rejected.

If you don't pass a valid audience as a parameter to `decode`, you'll get an exception:

> InvalidAudienceError('Invalid audience')

If you pass the valid audience, like in this example:

```
import jwt
import base64

token = "abc"

secret = base64.urlsafe_b64decode("XYZ=")
allowed_audience = "6A00574AE5514C1C90D2D5332FEF78F9"

decoded = jwt.decode(token, secret, audience = allowed_audience)
print(decoded)
```

it works fine.

Comment: Yes this worked. So I was missing to add audience :) Thanks

Comment: finally it works, glad to help. But why you didn't have any error messages or exceptions?

Comment: I was directly checking it in Postman with try except without raising an error. Saying
`if decoded : token valid else: Token invalid`

Comment: I worked directly in idle, so I see every exception. Makes life easier.